# How to bypass beforeRouteLeave Nuxtjs components

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I use `beforeRouteLeave` for open `dialog component` when calling component with `router`.

```js
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  if (to.name === "read-content") {
    this.displayProductModal(to);
  } else {
    next();
  }
},
```

When I call nuxt-link to the `read-content` (route.name) page a dialog opens. Sometimes I don't want to run the dialog. But I want to access that page directly, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, i use condition in parameter `to` -> `if(to.hash)` *add token or fake param after `route/#` url*.
If there is any other better way please suggest me.

```js
:to="{
  name: 'read-content',
  params: { content: id },
  hash: '#x',
}"
```